# Filtering special characters in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2014

This is question pertaining to SQL Server 2014. I have a table `xxx`. There is a column `col1` of type `varchar`. The values in this column can have alphanumeric characters like `1A324G`. There can also be special characters along with alphanumeric like `!2A93C` or `#AC934D`, etc.

There can be any special character (eg: `!$#^().-_`) in a value for this column. I wanted to extract data with only alphanumeric values and NOT any special characters in it. I was trying to use the `LIKE` clause with wildcard search pattern but I am not able to weed out the ones with only alphanumeric values.

Can someone please help me and let me know how I can do it?

Comment: Please post example of the code that you've tried in a question. It will help you clear your mind, and direct me where not to go.

Comment: Hi, for example assuming i've 2 values in the col1 column: 1GHD5343HS3435368 and !GE9343DGE5934435. i want to extract only 1GHD5343HS3435368 in the result. i tried something like select * from xxx where col1 like '%[0-9][A-Z][^!]%', but it doesn't seem to work. i'm not sure how i can use the wildcard pattern search in the LIKE clause. Also instead of the ! there could be a $ in the col1 value. There could be combo of special chars and alphanumeric. Can you please let me know how i can filter only the alphanumeric values in the select statement. Or should i write a stored proc for this.

Answer (score -1):

It's been a while since I've played with sql but something like this should work.

SELECT *
FROM xxx
WHERE col1 NOT LIKE '%!%' OR '%$%';

Comment: This does not exclude all fields with non-alpha values.

Comment: i tried something like the below and it seems to work: 

    select distinct col1 from xxx
    where col1  like '%!%'
    or col1 like '%@%'
    or col1 like '%#%'
    or col1 like '%$%'
    or col1 like '%&%'
    or col1 like '%*%'
    or col1 like '%`%'
    or col1 like '%''%'
    or col1 like '%?%'
    or col1 like '%.%'
    or col1 like '%-%'
    or col1 like '%+%'